# When do I get 2B's and A2's outfits?

Tags: nier-automata

In the 3C3C1D119440927 DLC, I got 9S's outfit after the first round in the underground colosseum in the Forest Area, but when I played as 2B, I did two of the Trials of Sand trials and two rounds in the colosseum in the Flooded City, but I didn't get any outfits.

As 9S, I'm up to the Lv. 70 Recommended Match in the underground colosseum in the Forest Area and Trials of Sand trials, but I've still gotten no more outfits. When do I get 2B's and A2's outfits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get 2B and A2's outfits, you need to do more in their respective Colosseums than you had to for 9S's costume, which only required you to beat the first trial.

To get the Revealing Outfit for 2B, you need to win the rank S challenge in the Flooded City Arena. This is the sixth rank of challenges in this arena.

Similarly, for A2's alternate costume, you need to beat the 6th trial in the Desert Arena. It's worth mentioning that you don't have to do this with A2, as I beat the first six trials in this arena as 2B.